# Advantages of filling up all occupations of a building

Tags: ios, pixel-people

In Pixel People, you can assign a certain occupation to multiple buildings. For example, a mathematician can be assigned to a university or to a tech support center. This makes it impossible to 'fill up' all the buildings with the correct occupation unless you splice duplicates. Is there any advantage at all for filling up all the occupations of a building?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you get the bank building, fully occupied buildings produce twice as many coins.